# HTML email Blackberry

Tags: email, blackberry, html-email

I have the following code to open the Blackberry email composer with a predefined email:

```
Message m = new Message();
m.setContent("Body");
m.setSubject("Subject");

Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MESSAGES, new MessageArguments(m));
```

Can I put HTML code as the email content?
I want to have some **bold** text and a web link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [this BlackBerry forum](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-Message-with-embedded-image/td-p/581373), it looks like people are having trouble with using `Message.setContent(String)`.  You might want to try adding the message content as a multipart html part.

Here's some [example code for that](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0504.html).  That one is standard Java, though, so it's just meant to give you a rough idea of what's involved with multipart messages.

Here's a [BlackBerry multipart example](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11935/Send_msg_with_attachment_565471_11.jsp).  I would think you could do this, by setting the content type of your body part to `text/html`.